# If an FCN accept rectangular image as input or has to be square?

Tags: tensorflow, cnn, pytorch, image-preprocessing, image-segmentation

Some say that for `FCN` it doesn't matter if the input image is `rectangular` the only thing matters that the size must be constant for training and production jobs, however there are many researches say that the image has to be `squared` and therefore they introduce either resampling image by one of the existing methods such as `nearest neighbour` and alternatively use one padding approach such as `zero-padding` to reduce the effect of distorted image for training and production job. So I am little bit confused...any help to clarify the issue is appreciated.

Also that if using `Pytorch` or Tensrflow make any difference here?